# iCarousel Linear Infinite Effect?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, icarousel

I would to ask how to create an iCarousel with linear infinite effect? 
What I mean is, it is the combination of linear and rotary type.
For example, numbers 1-10 is being displayed in a linear manner, then next to 10 is 1.

Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, set your carousel to wrap by implementing

```
- (BOOL)carouselShouldWrap:(iCarousel *)carousel {
//wrap all carousels
return YES;
}
```

Next, you may use NSTimer to initiate the scrolling. For example:

```
self.scrollTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(scrollCarousel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void)scrollCarousel {
 NSInteger newIndex=self.carousel.currentItemIndex++;
 if (newIndex > self.carousel.numberOfItems) {
   newIndex=0;
 }

 [self.carousel scrollToItemAtIndex:newIndex duration:5]; // takes 5 seconds to scroll

}
```